# Best Way to Abstract Initializing Attributes

Tags: ruby, abstraction

What's the best way to abstract this pattern:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar

  def initialize(foo, bar)
    @foo, @bar = foo, bar
  end
end
```

A good solution should take superclasses into consideration **and** be able to handle still being able to have an initializer to do more things. Extra points for not sacrificing performance in your solution.

Comment: That's really vague. What part of it do you want to abstract? How do you want to abstract it?

Comment: Also, you could try asking here: http://refactormycode.com

Comment: I want to either create a module that I can mix into classes or override Class itself so that I can write a single line of code and have it create the accessors and the initializer.

Comment: Do you need to be able to specify non-attr_accessor params to initialize? Are you envisioning generational ordering of attrs from superclases in the signature?

Comment: I'm not sure... I'd like to avoid losing the initializer created by initialize_with if a new initializer is created, but I understand that that introduces some confusion around the method signature. Maybe you'd do: Foo.new(new_arg, new_arg2, :foo => 1, :bar => 2)? That seems potentially confusing as well. Thoughts?

Comment: I would probably go with foo.new{user_param, :user_option => option_value, :attrs => {:foo => 1, :bar => 2}}.  It's a bit verbose, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

You could even class_eval the attr_accessors in just from calling initialize, if they don't exist yet on the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution to that problem already (partially) [exists](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Struct.html), but if you want a more declarative approach in your classes then the following should work.

```
class Class
  def initialize_with(*attrs, &block)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      attr_accessor attr
    end
    (class << self; self; end).send :define_method, :new do |*args|
      obj = allocate
      init_args, surplus_args = args[0...attrs.size], args[attrs.size..-1]
      attrs.zip(init_args) do |attr, arg|
        obj.instance_variable_set "@#{attr}", arg
      end
      obj.send :initialize, *surplus_args
      obj
    end
  end
end
```

You can now do:

```
class MyClass < ParentClass
  initialize_with :foo, :bar
  def initialize(baz)
    @initialized = true
    super(baz) # pass any arguments to initializer of superclass
  end
end
my_obj = MyClass.new "foo", "bar", "baz"
my_obj.foo #=> "foo"
my_obj.bar #=> "bar"
my_obj.instance_variable_get(:@initialized) #=> true
```

Some characteristics of this solution:

- Specify constructor attributes with `initialize_with`
- Optionally use `initialize` to do custom initialization
- Possible to call `super` in `initialize`
- Arguments to `initialize` are the arguments that were not consumed by attributes specified with `initialize_with`
- Easily extracted into a Module
- Constructor attributes specified with `initialize_with` are inherited, but defining a new set on a child class will remove the parent attributes
- Dynamic solution probably has performance hit

If you want to create a solution with absolute minimal performance overhead, it would be not that difficult to refactor *most* of the functionality into a string which can be `eval`ed when the initializer is defined. I have not benchmarked what the difference would be.

Note: I found that hacking `new` works better than hacking `initialize`. If you define `initialize` with metaprogramming, you'd probably get a scenario where you pass a block to `initialize_with` as a substitute initializer, and it's not possible to use `super` in a block.

Comment: This solution looks pretty good. It seems like you would be able to call zsuper (super without parens or arguments), i.e. super instead of super(baz). I'd definitely like to see a solution that did not require define_method and could avoid using instance_variable_set. As you pointed out, this would probably require String eval.

Comment: I'm accepting this solution even though it uses define_method. I'll submit my own answer below tomorrow for everyone's consideration.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first solution that comes to my mind. There's one big downside in my module: you must define the class initialize method before including the module or it won't work.

There's probably a better solution for that problem, but this is what I wrote in less than a couple of minutes.

Also, I didn't keep performances too much into consideration. You probably can find a much better solution than me, especially talking about performances. ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU

require 'rubygems'
require 'activesupport'


module Initializable

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      extend  ClassMethods
      include InstanceMethods
      alias_method_chain :initialize, :attributes
      class_inheritable_array :attr_initializable
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def attr_initialized(*attrs)
      attrs.flatten.each do |attr|
        attr_accessor attr
      end
      self.attr_initializable = attrs.flatten
    end

  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def initialize_with_attributes(*args)
      values = args.dup
      self.attr_initializable.each do |attr|
        self.send(:"#{attr}=", values.shift)
      end
      initialize_without_attributes(values)
    end

  end

end


class MyClass1
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar

  def initialize(foo, bar)
    @foo, @bar = foo, bar
  end
end

class MyClass2

  def initialize(*args)
  end

  include Initializable

  attr_initialized :foo, :bar
end


if $0 == __FILE__
  require 'test/unit'

  class InitializableTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

    def test_equality
      assert_equal MyClass1.new("foo1", "bar1").foo, MyClass2.new("foo1", "bar1").foo
      assert_equal MyClass1.new("foo1", "bar1").bar, MyClass2.new("foo1", "bar1").bar
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: I'd pretty much reject this solution out of hand for the ActiveSupport dependency.  Any dependency for this sort of thing would be undesirable, but requiring the most heinous Ruby library around just adds insult to injury.

Comment: I used ActiveSupport just to take advantage of alias_method_chain but you don't need it at all. You can use alias.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass < Struct.new(:foo, :bar)
end
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you add an initializer with arguments, it wipes the default Struct initializer.

Comment: You can still do stuff like:

    class MyClass < Struct.new(:foo, :bar)
      def initialize(*args)
        options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : {}
        super
      end
    end

    # or

    class MyClass < Struct.new(:foo, :bar)
      def initialize(baz, *args)
        super(*args)
      end
    end

Comment: I like class MyClass < Struct.new(:foo, :bar); def initialize(baz, *args) @baz = baz; super(*args) end; end

Comment: I found that inheriting from Struct.new() breaks Rails code auto-reloading and also leads to TypeErrors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785694/superclass-mismatch-struct-reloading-and-spork

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question with perfectly acceptable answers but I wanted to post my solution as it takes advantage of `Module#prepend` (new in Ruby 2.2) and the fact that modules are also classes for very simple solution. First the module to make the magic:

```
class InitializeWith < Module
  def initialize *attrs
    super() do
      define_method :initialize do |*args|
        attrs.each { |attr| instance_variable_set "@#{attr}", args.shift }
        super *args
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now let's use our fancy module:

```
class MyClass
  prepend InitializeWith.new :foo, :bar
end
```

Note that I left our the `attr_accessible` stuff as I consider that a separate concern although it would be trivial to support. Now I can create an instance with:

```
MyClass.new 'baz', 'boo'
```

I can still define an `initialize` for custom initialization. If my custom `initialize` take an argument those will be any extra arguments provided to the new instance. So:

```
class MyClass
  prepend InitializeWith.new :foo, :bar

  def initialize extra
    puts extra
  end
end
MyClass.new 'baz', 'boo', 'dog'
```

In the above example `@foo='baz'`, `@bar='boo'` and it will print `dog`.

What I also like about this solution is that it doesn't pollute the global namespace with a DSL. Objects that want this functionality can `prepend`. Everybody else is untouched.

Answer (score 0):

This module allows an attrs hash as an option to new().  You can include the module in a class with inheritance, and the constructor still works.

I like this better than a list of attr values as parameters, because, particularly with inherited attrs, I wouldn't like trying to remember which param was which.

```
module Attrize
  def initialize(*args)
    arg = args.select{|a| a.is_a?(Hash) && a[:attrs]}
    if arg
      arg[0][:attrs].each do |key, value|
        self.class.class_eval{attr_accessor(key)} unless respond_to?(key)
        send(key.to_s + '=', value)
      end
      args.delete(arg[0])
    end
    (args == []) ? super : super(*args)
  end
end

class Hue
  def initialize(transparent)
    puts "I'm transparent" if transparent
  end
end

class Color < Hue
  include Attrize
  def initialize(color, *args)
    p color
    super(*args)
    p "My style is " + @style if @style
  end
end
```

And you can do this:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'attrize'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> c = Color.new("blue", false)
"blue"
=> #<Color:0x201df4>
irb(main):003:0>  c = Color.new("blue", true, :attrs => {:style => 'electric'})
"blue"
I'm transparent
"My style is electric"
```