# Superclass mismatch, Struct, reloading and Spork

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, spork

Suppose there's the following class

```
# derp.rb
class Derp < Struct.new :id
end
```

When I `load "./derp.rb"` twice the program fails with `TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Derp`. Ok, this could be managed with `require`. But how can I reload such classes for each test run with Spork? `require` obviously won't work cause it caches the loaded files.

Answer (score 6):

`Struct.new` is creating new class for your every load.

```
irb(main):001:0> class Test1 < Struct.new :id; end
nil
irb(main):003:0> class Test1 < Struct.new :id; end
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Test1
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

You can save your `Struct.new` returned `class` to a variable and you
can use that will be always the same `class`.

```
irb(main):004:0> Id = Struct.new :id
#<Class:0x00000002c35b20>
irb(main):005:0> class Test2 < Id; end
nil
irb(main):006:0> class Test2 < Id; end
nil
```

or You can use `Struct.new` block style instead of `class` keyword it
will only give `warning: already initialized constant Test3` when you
reload your file.

```
irb(main):023:0> Test3 = Struct.new(:id) do
                     def my_methods
                     "this is a method"
                     end
                   end
```

Comment: I see. But this won't help me with Spork: creating constants for each kind of Struct kinda defeats the purpose

Comment: @synapse `Struct.new` is always returning new class. maybe you can split same type of methods (can be created with accessors) to modules and `include` them.

Answer (score 3):

You can make sure the struct class is created only once.

`Test1 < $test1 ||= Struct.new(:id)`

Comment: This works but will cause warnings. Like this warning: already initialized constant WebCalendarHelper::MonthCalendar::HEADER

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this on Google, this is what solved it for me:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    MyClassStruct ||= Struct.new(:id)
    SomeStruct < MyClassStruct
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dignoe. Their solution work for me when trying to eager loading:

```
class D::Potencia < Struct.new(:potencia_instalada)
end
```

That gave me SuperClass MisMatch on rspec test.

Failure/Error: class D::Potencia < Struct.new(:potencia_instalada)

TypeError:
superclass mismatch for class Potencia

Now we can perform test on all code base before publishing to production.

```
module D
  ClasePotenciaInstalada ||= Struct.new(:potencia_instalada)
  class D::Potencia < ClasePotenciaInstalada
  end
end
```